# How to make user output in decreasing order?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I have tried using `Arrays.sort(int, Collections.reverseOrder());`
but that doesn't seem to want to work. I am trying to get the output in decreasing order. Does it have to be in the for loop? Or in the `System.out.print()` that I use at the very end?

```
public class EmployeeWorkHours {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

          Scanner turtle = new Scanner(System.in);
          String[] calender = { "S", "M", "T", "W", "Th", "F", "S" };
          System.out.println("How many Employee's do you have?: ");
          int NUMBER_OF_EMPLOYEES = turtle.nextInt();
          turtle.nextLine();

          int [][]hours;
          int[] totalHours= new int[NUMBER_OF_EMPLOYEES];

          hours = new int[NUMBER_OF_EMPLOYEES][7];
          String[] employee = new String[NUMBER_OF_EMPLOYEES];

          // input for Names
          for (int x = 0; x < (employee.length); x++) {
              System.out.println("Name of Employee " + (x + 1) + ": ");
              String name = turtle.nextLine();
              employee[x] = name;

          }
          // input for Hours
          for (int z = 0; z < employee.length; z++) {
              System.out.println("Starting from Sunday, enter the hours Employee "+ (z + 1)+ " has worked each day (Make sure you seperate it by spaces): ");
              for (int a = 0; a < 7; a++) {
                  hours[z][a] = turtle.nextInt();
              }
              turtle.nextLine();
          }
          // Print everything out
          for (int i = 0; i < employee.length; i++) {
              totalHours[i]=0;
              for(int j=0; j<7; j ++){
                  totalHours[i] = totalHours[i]+hours[i][j];   
              }

              System.out.println("Employee " + (i + 1) +" worked " + totalHours[i] + " hours");          
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that you have written?

Comment: Okay it's up above...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Collections.sort(arraylist, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Or

```
Collections.sort(list);
Collections.reverse(list);
```

It also depends what implementation of collections you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at  [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/collections_reverseorder.htm).

More specificaly this part of the link

```
  Comparator cmp = Collections.reverseOrder();  

   // sort the list
   Collections.sort(list, cmp);  

   System.out.println("List sorted in ReverseOrder: ");      
   for(int i : list){
        System.out.println(i+ " ");
   }
```